# XPATH method for retuning multiple dynamic results from a XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a form that the user types or selects a value the form is as follows

```
<form id="search_photos" action="photo_result.php" method="get">
<select name="Photographer_id" id="Photographer_id"   style="height:23px; border:1px solid Silver;">
    <option selected="selected" value="x">Any Photographer_id</option>
    <option value="John">John</option>
    <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
    <option value="Joseph">Joseph</option>
</select>
<select name="Photographer_id" id="Photographer_id"   style="height:23px; border:1px solid Silver;">
    <option selected="selected" value="x">Any Photographer_id</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="images" id="images"   style="height:23px; border:1px solid Silver;">
    <option selected="selected" value="x">All Images</option>
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="a">Image a</option>
    <option value="b">Image b </option>
    <option value="c">Image c </option>
</select>
    <select name="images_id" id="images_id"   style="height:23px; border:1px solid Silver;">
    <option selected="selected" value="x">All Images</option>
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input name="Submit" value="Search Now &gt;" id="Submit" class="Adv1_Filter_Button" type="submit">
```

Then the `search_photo.php` script  that catches the result of the form and filters the values entered by the user as follows

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("photo.xml");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml); $i++) {  

    if (isset($_GET["LocationName"])) {
        $photographer_id = $_GET["LocationName"];
    }

    $result = $xml->xpath('/root/area[photographer_id="' . $photographer_id . '"]  ');
}

if(isset($_GET["Photographer"])) {
    $photographer = $_GET["Photographer"];
} 

$result = $xml->xpath('/root/area[photographer_id="' . $photographer_id . '"]  ');

if(isset($_GET["images"])) {
    $image = $_GET["images"];
}

echo $photographer_id;
echo $photographer;
echo $image;
var_dump ($result);
```

The `$result` from the first XPATH pass is correct  if all that is set is ‘photographer_id’ if I then  try `$result = $xml->xpath('/root/area[photographer_id="' . $photographer_id . '"] | /root/area[photographer="' . $photographer . '"]');`  and select `1` and `fred` then I get the result of an array of all four when it should be an empty array can advise how to correct this error.
Sorry michi  here is the XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
   <area>
    <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
    <photographer>John</photographer>
    <image>a</image>
    <image_id>1</image_id>
   </area>
   <area>
    <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
    <photographer>John</photographer>
    <image>b</image>
    <image_id>2</image_id>
   </area>
   <area>
    <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
    <photographer>John</photographer>
    <image>c</image>
    <image_id>3</image_id>
   </area>
   <area>
    <photographer_id>2</photographer_id>
    <photographer>Fred</photographer>
    <image>a</image>
    <image_id>4</image_id>
   </area>
   <area>
    <photographer_id>3</photographer_id>
    <photographer>Joseph</photographer>
    <image>a</image>
    <image_id>5</image_id>
   </area>
  </root>
```

does this help, the final XML file will be larger than this though.

Comment: Try using & (and) instead of | (or)

Comment: tried useing & (and) just get an empty array as $result also though of saving $result as an xml file and using xpath on the second xml file or would it be easy to convert $result to an object

Comment: @Artful_dodger: edit your question and include the XML, please.

Comment: Something is wrong with the code in your question. Please double-check and remove anything that is not necessarily part of the example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi had a simillar problem with a long in script, I have taken the idea from there and came up with this i hope it helps

```
<?php
```

$xml = simplexml_load_file("photo.xml");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml); $i++){

```
if(isset($_GET["LocationName"]))
{
    $photographer_id = $_GET["LocationName"];
}

$result = $xml->xpath('/root/area[photographer_id="' . $photographer_id . '"]  ');
}


if(isset($_GET["photographer"]))
{
    $photographer = $_GET["photographer"];
} 

if(isset($_GET["images"]))
{
    $image = $_GET["images"];

    //$result = $xml->xpath('/root/area[photographer_id="' . $photographer_id . '"] and /root/area[photographer="' . $photographer . '"]');
```

}

```
//echo $photographer_id;
//echo $photographer;
//echo $image;

$filteredResult = array();

foreach($result as $obj){
    if(in_array($photographer, (array)$obj) == 1 || $photographer == 'x'){ 
        if(in_array($image, (array)$obj) || $image == 'x'){
            array_push($filteredResult, $obj);
        }
    }
}

foreach($filteredResult as &$obj){
    //how to access values in the object
    echo $obj->{'photographer'};
    echo $obj->{'image'};
}
echo $obj->{'image'};

    ?>
```

the last echo should give you some pointers

Comment: user2033464 this seems to be the easiest to implement thanks m8

Comment: noticed an error when using 'echo $obj->{image'};' only displayed the first object and not all so I tried '$filteredResult[$i]->image' to display all instances of the image node

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:
(1) **get the filter values from the form and build a querystring for xpath:**

```
$fields = array( // fieldname => value for "all"
    'photographer_id' => '',
    'photographer' => 'x',
    'image' => '0');

foreach ($fields as $fieldname => $fieldvalue)
    if (isset($_GET[$fieldname]) && trim($_GET[$fieldname]) != $fieldvalue)
    $query[] = "$fieldname = '$_GET[$fieldname]'";

if (isset($query)) 
    $query = "[" . implode(' or ', $query) . "]"; else $query = "";
```

(2) **use xpath to filter XML and display selected nodes**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$results = $xml->xpath("area$query");

foreach ($results as $result) 
    echo "image $result->image by $result->photographer ($result->photographer_id)<br />";
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ciboJg

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want, since your question isn't quite clear. Even so I've [coded a little snippet](http://codepad.org/tjulWzq3) to show you how you can work with XPath conditions to retrieve the `area` nodes you want for a given selection on the form.

Just think of the values on the `$examples` array as possible values submitted on the form.

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <area>
        <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
        <photographer>John</photographer>
        <image>a</image>
    </area>
    <area>
        <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
        <photographer>John</photographer>
        <image>b</image>
    </area>
    <area>
        <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
        <photographer>John</photographer>
        <image>c</image>
    </area>
    <area>
        <photographer_id>2</photographer_id>
        <photographer>Fred</photographer>
        <image>a</image>
    </area>
</root>
XML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$examples = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John'),
    array('name' => 'Fred'),
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Fred'),
);

foreach ($examples as $example) {
    $conditions = array();

    if (!empty($example['id'])) {
        $conditions[] = "photographer_id = {$example['id']}";
    }

    if (!empty($example['name'])) {
        $conditions[] = "photographer = '{$example['name']}'";
    }

    $xpath_condition = implode(' and ', $conditions);
    echo "{$xpath_condition}\n";
    $area = $sxe->xpath("//area[{$xpath_condition}]");

    print_r($area);
}
```

#### Output:

```
photographer_id = 1 and photographer = 'John'
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [photographer_id] => 1
            [photographer] => John
            [image] => a
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [photographer_id] => 1
            [photographer] => John
            [image] => b
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [photographer_id] => 1
            [photographer] => John
            [image] => c
        )
)
photographer = 'Fred'
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [photographer_id] => 2
            [photographer] => Fred
            [image] => a
        )
)
photographer_id = 1 and photographer = 'Fred'
Array
(
)
```

Comment: Hi Rolando just trying out your example of code what would I need to change in your code so that the user could dynamically change the values of the array ie say the user only wanted to see the results of john with image c, I have got user2033464 code to work with one floor and that is if the user enters say a number value (1) then the query results are wrong but if they enter a string value ay (one) then the query results are correct any help most appreciated as I am relatively new to php still ready the manual

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the best way would be for your to implement a form for the user to fill, assign some values on the form to the XPath query to filter the results accordingly.

Comment: Hi Rolando yes that is correct that is what I have done, I a have tried to implement user2033464 code but on the final query I get the wrong results so I looking other methods to filter the results

Comment: I think the problem with this code foreach($result as $obj){
    if(in_array($photographer, (array)$obj) == 1 || $photographer == 'x'){ 
        if(in_array($image, (array)$obj) || $image == 'x'){
            array_push($filteredResult, $obj) maybe this part of the code if(in_array($image, (array)$obj) but I do not have enough experience yet to debug this problem

Comment: You better ask a new question with your full problem description.

Comment: Hi Rolando looking to my problem found this piece on Drill down data and recursion  do think this is the way to go for solving the problem