# query error on search result of a xml file

Tags: php, xml, search

I have a created a small query search for a xml file my problem is that when search with the photographer_id selected as it is a number ie 1,2,3 ect I get the rong result but if I change the form and xml file from 1 to one and 2 to two  the search works fine I have tries casting the values from the get request and photographer_id to an integer with (int) and is numeric but same results

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("photo.xml");


   for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml); $i++){

    if(isset($_GET["LocationName"])) 

    {
       $photographer = $_GET["LocationName"];
    }

    $result = $xml->xpath('/root/area[photographer="' . $photographer . '"]  ');
    }


    if(isset($_GET["photographer_id"]))
    {
        $photographer_id = $_GET["photographer_id"];
    } 

    if(isset($_GET["images"]))
    {
        $image = $_GET["images"];
        }

    //echo $photographer_id;
    //echo $photographer;
    //echo $image;

    $filteredResult = array();

    foreach($result as $obj){
        if(in_array($photographer_id, (array)$obj)  || $photographer_id == 'x'){ 
            if(in_array($image, (array)$obj) || $image == 'x'){
                array_push($filteredResult, $obj);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($filteredResult as &$obj){
        //how to access values in the object
        //echo $obj->{'photographer'};
        echo $obj->{'image'};
        }
        if (empty($filteredResult)) {
    echo 'Empty';
}
```

I have tried debug this piece of code but still can't figure out where I am going wrong

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
   <area>
    <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
    <photographer>John</photographer>
    <image>a</image>
    <image_id>1</image_id>
   </area>
   <area>
    <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
    <photographer>John</photographer>
    <image>b</image>
    <image_id>2</image_id>
   </area>
   <area>
    <photographer_id>1</photographer_id>
    <photographer>John</photographer>
    <image>c</image>
    <image_id>3</image_id>
   </area>
   <area>
    <photographer_id>2</photographer_id>
    <photographer>Fred</photographer>
    <image>a</image>
    <image_id>4</image_id>
   </area>
   <area>
    <photographer_id>3</photographer_id>
    <photographer>Joseph</photographer>
    <image>a</image>
    <image_id>5</image_id>
   </area>
  </root>
```

this question is not about XPATH, the XPATH search works fine its about why the search query 'one' returns correctly and yet if '1' is used the search pattern is incorrect

Comment: can you show your xml?

Comment: the idea is that the user can search the site for primarily the photographer and the id of the photographer to be linked to the image so if the refine their search of images by id I hope that makes sence

Comment: when I use a form to search the xml file for photographer_id I would like to display the result on the get request ie if photographer_id 1 is selected I would like to display only the photographer with id 1and the images of photographer_id 1 if I change the value of photographer_id in the xml file from 1 to One the query work fine so what I guess I trying to work out is what is the differance between string'1'and string 'One'

Comment: I can't believe it, you asked the very same question  on May 18, and I answered it there... what's up? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629935/xpath-method-for-retuning-multiple-dynamic-results-from-a-xml-file-using-php/16636794#16636794

Comment: I think after revuing boths your answers as a beginger in php its hard to learn something when you spend more time sorting out the errors that you do not total understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my edited code including everything (PHP and HTML, all in 1 page).
I use `$_POST` over `$_GET` for safety reasons.

```
<!-- here's the complete <head> etc. -->
<body>
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // form has been sent, process and show results...

    // get data
    $id  = $_POST['id'];
    $img = $_POST['img'];

    if ($id <> '*') $id = "'$id'";
    if ($img <> '*') $img = "'$img'"; // wrap $id/$img in '' if is isn't *   

    $results = $xml->xpath("//area[photographer_id=$id and image=$img]");

    echo "<h1>search results</h1><p>results found: ". count($results) . "</p>";        

    // show results
    foreach ($results as $r)
    echo "result #" . ++$c . ": $r->photographer_id, $r->photographer, image: $r->image<br />"; 

} else { // form not sent, display form

    // get lists of unique ids / images from XML
    $ids = $imgs = array();
    foreach ($xml->area as $a) {
        $ids[(string)$a->photographer_id] = (string)$a->photographer;
        $imgs[(string)$a->image] =(string)$a->image;
    }
    ?>

<h1>Search</h1>
<form method="post">
    <label for="id">select a photographer</label>
    <select name ="id" id="id" size="1">
        <option value="*" selected="selected">all</option>
<?php // edit: typo corrected in NEXT LINE at value=\"$id\"
foreach ($ids as $id => $name) echo "<option value=\"$id\">$name ($id)</option>";
?>
    </select>
    <label for="img">select a photographer</label>
    <select name ="img" id="img" size="1">
        <option value="*" selected="selected">all</option>
<?php
foreach ($imgs as $img) echo "<option value=\"$img\">$img</option>";
?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />    
</form>
<?php
} // if isset
?>
</body>
</html>
```

see the PHP part working: https://eval.in/37100

Comment: the code you have does not return a result based on any user input as I have form with three dropdown lists where the user can select by photograger,id or image the only part of the search I am having trouble with is id because it use 1,2,3ect if I change the values to One,Two Three ect then the search works fine I thought that it maybe because it was a string so I tried changing to interger with (int) but the results of the search did not change

Comment: I have played around with this for a while I get differnt results if add a 0 ie 01 it appears that the problem is with 01 and 02, 03 onwards work fine I tried it on different pc to no avail, makes no sence to me either

Comment: Just had a thought my complete xml file has an image_id element to identify the images could the image_id and photographer_id be causing the query error and if so any ideas as how I can resolve I'll test and check results

Comment: sorry but I am getting this error on the works pc 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\test search\test.php on line 39' so I'll test it out when I get home cheers michi

Comment: @Artful_dodger: sorry, typo, corrected it and marked it with a comment in the code.

Comment: Hi michi just made the changes to line 39 to "value='\$id\'" but I am now getting two line erro'Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\wamp\www\final_search\test3.php on line 28' not sure what is causing that but it may help me hone my debug skill  I'll keep you posted

Comment: hi michi just checked out what Michael Berkowski advised in an earlier post and that is SimpleXMLElement need to be typed as strings

Comment: Hi michi thank you for your help so far I do have one more question as so far the method you have used works best,I note that you have two queries in the xpath code if I need to add one more value to the query is that possible and would the syntax be  $results = $xml->xpath("//area[photographer_id=$id and image=$img and image_id=$image_id]"); any help would be appriciated

Comment: @Artful_dodger your query looks good to me, does it give you the results you want?

Comment: well I am just experimenting abd if I add the third query I get no results so I must have made a mistake somewhere else good to know that I am slowly getting to grips with this problem though my eye sight is suffering

Comment: just run a new test on that piece of code and its done the trick cheers again for for you Patience it was a typo on my part, so is there a limit on how many elements you can add to XPATH query

Comment: @Artful_dodger Cheers to you, too ;-)